# Trouble with installation of Anaconda 2020.02

Tags: anaconda

Whenever I try to install Anaconda, Anaconda Navigator, Anaconda Prompt then all other applications are not included in the Anaconda3 folder. Is there any reason for this? I'm unable to find a solution for this.

Comment: are you installing on Windows, Linux or Apple?